# Tranlate NUSOAP to PHP5's SOAPClient

Tags: php, soap, nusoap, soap-client

I cannot get PHP5 there for i try using NUSOAP as alternative as PHP5's SoapClient.

How can i translate this PHP5 SoapClient code into NUSOAP?

```
 $epay_params = array();
$epay_params['merchantnumber'] = "ENTER YOUR MERCHANT NUMBER HERE";
$epay_params['subscriptionid'] = "ENTER THE SUBSCRIPTIONID RETURNED FROM EPAY HERE";
$epay_params['orderid'] = "1234";
$epay_params['amount'] = "9995";
$epay_params['currency'] = "208";
$epay_params['instantcapture'] = "0";
$epay_params['fraud'] = "0";
$epay_params['transactionid'] = "-1";
$epay_params['pbsresponse'] = "-1";
$epay_params['epayresponse'] = "-1";

$client = new SoapClient('https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/subscription.asmx?WSDL');

$result = $client->authorize($epay_params);

if($result->authorizeResult == true)
{
    $transactionid = $result->transactionid;
}
else
{
    //Error - see pbsresponse and epayresponse
}
```

I tried something like this, but i don't understand anything.

```
include("lib/nusoap.php");
$epay_params = array();
$epay_params['merchantnumber'] = $Payments->merchantnumber;
$epay_params['subscriptionid'] = $_POST['subscriptionname'];
$epay_params['orderid'] = $_POST['orderid'];
$epay_params['amount'] = $_POST['amount'];
$epay_params['currency'] = $_POST['currency'];
$epay_params['instantcapture'] = "0";
$epay_params['fraud'] = "0";
$epay_params['transactionid'] = "-1";
$epay_params['pbsresponse'] = "-1";
$epay_params['epayresponse'] = "-1";


$client = new nusoap_client('https://ssl.ditonlinebetalingssystem.dk/remote/subscription.asmx?WSDL','wsdl');
$client->call("transactionid", $epay_params);

echo $client->authorizeResult;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Can you clarify if you are trying to delete entries that are 15 minutes old on a local server or on a remote server?

I do this for my website against entries on my local MySQL database by writing a sql command that is then scheduled as a cronjob. Works flawlessly.

If your issue is to delete records on a remote database, make sure you can query it first. The API might not accept certain SQL statements such as DELETE.

Comment: Sorry, the title was autocompleted, so it a earlier thread, i have updaded it.

Comment: Try this article
[link]http://stackoverflow.com/questions/322510/moving-from-nusoap-to-php5-soap

Comment: I said i cannot use SoapClient as PHP5. So therefore i use NUSOAP.

Comment: Okay, so really what you're trying to do is move from PHP's builtin soapclient to NUSOAP's nusoap_client, the reverse of what the title of the post conveys. Try this link instead then for some clarification on this:

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2420103/disable-native-soap-class-in-php5-and-use-nusoap